# Max Memory only 880 MB in Java Program

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, ram

I'm trying to create a HashMap for a dataset that has 4400 records and 27000 features. I have increased the max limit to 4G in the .ini file of eclipse. But, when I print the maxMemory in the java program, it shows as 880 MB. I tried with different values of xms and xmx

I'm unsure why this is selecting only 880 MB ?

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

I get this error at the end. If I prevent this by changing .ini file, I get heap error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the xms and xmx in eclipse.ini will increase the memory for eclipse process.If you want to change the memory for your program ,you should provide xmx and xms JVM arguments in Run Configuration of eclipse while running your program.
-Xms1000m -Xmx1500m

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much. I was struggling from last 10 hours on this issue. :(

Answer (score 4):

you should increase JVM's max heap size.
in eclipse you will have to set it in debug configuration --> arguments.
Find min/max param name for your JVM version from google .
I am using HotSpot and the param name is  -Xms2000m -Xmx2000m